# Angular simple validation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-validation

[Here is some plunker I have created](http://plnkr.co/edit/zD0YkM8fi8nNrVRqQxY1?p=preview). I cant understand why it is not working.
Here is the JS:

```
  angular.module('demo', [
  ]).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope)
  {
    $scope.name = "Vlad";
    $scope.age = 11;

    $scope.sendTest = function() 
    {
      console.log($scope.name.$valid);
      console.log($scope.age.$valid);
    }
  });
```

Here is the html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="form" novalidate>
            <p>
                <label>Number: </label>
                <input type="text" min="0" max="10" ng-model="age" required />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Name: </label>
               <input type="text" ng-model="name" required />
            </p>
            <button ng-click="sendTest(test)">Submit</button>
        </form>
  </body>
```

The problem is that I am getting undefined in the console (instead of `true`, `false`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things.

You need to access the form fields via the form object

```
console.log($scope.form.name.$valid);
console.log($scope.form.age.$valid);
```

And to be able to do that, you need to set the `name` attribute on the inputs

```
<input type="number" name="age" min="0" max="10" ng-model="age" required />
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" required />
```

Well, three things. You need `input type="number"` for `min` and `max` to work. See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Comment: What if i have multiple forms? I will try to work it on the plunker.

Comment: Give them different names